# Deallocating struct in C outside function

Tags: c, object, struct, avr-gcc

I am creating struct object in my code and I want to destroy this object. I know, for creating pointers I have to use `malloc()` to allocate and `free()` to deallocate pointer or array. But I have question about struct object. I was looking for answers here and I found solution to use brackets `{}` - placing struct object in brackets, so outside of right bracket struct object will be deallocated. But I am interested to deallocate object in global array. How can I deallocate such object? Example code

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned char m_some_property;
} my_struct;


static my_struct g_myStructArr[10];


int main(void)
{
  g_myStructArr[0].m_some_property = 20;
  // how to use brackets {} here to deallocate that object?
  return 0;
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: To deallocate  `g_myStructArr[]`, call `exit(-1);`, but of course that is extreme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, global variables will be allocated for the lifetime of the program. Also I don't understand why you want to, you should not worry about that since using global variables is very rarely needed. Global variables are allocated when the program starts and deallocated when it ends.

Comment: Thanks, I have an array in my program, and i am filling elements of this array with struct objects. Currently i have this array static (not dynamic). I want to destroy elements of this array when i don't need them. I have strange idea, to use free() and pass address of n element, but i think it wouldn't work: free(g_myStructArr + 2);

Comment: Why do you want to destroy them? Destroying often means reuse the space, so just do that. Add a field to the struct to tell whether it's occupied. Or use `malloc()` but I don't thing you should do it with `malloc()`.

Comment: Yes, it's static array, and malloc shouldn't be used here. I want to dynamically adds/fills elements of this array and dynamically remove elements. I have to implement stack. I have not enough memory in program and i am forced to deallocate every unnecessary variable/object in my program

Comment: @shx: There's a difference between implementing a stack object, and using stack memory to store values. You can `malloc` a struct/array, and manipulate that block of memory through functions like `stack_pop(my_struct **s)`, in which you `realloc` the pointer, and return the popped element. If needs must (but I'd advise against it), you could assign function pointers to that struct and, using macro's, make it look like you're calling the functions as methods (but again: I wouldn't!)

Comment: I think it's good idea. i could use global static array of struct pointers, but in this way i will have to use malloc. I would like to omit using malloc because of memory costs (i am writing my program on AVR microcontroller). Thanks for advice :)

Comment: @shx you'll have to set a maximum size for your stack and live with that memory usage, otherwise your program will run out of memory somewhere or other when the stack gets large

Answer (score -1):

An executable of a C program is divided into following sections:

**Text Segment:**

Machine code of binary is read into this section. Text segment is often read-only segment in order to prevent from being modified.

**Initialized Data Segment:**

All global, static, constant and external variables that are initialized are recorded into this section.

**Uninitialized Data Segment:**

This section contains all uninitialized global and static data and is initialized to zero before program starts executing.

**Heap:**

Almost all the dynamic memory allocations come from this section.

**Stack:**

This segment starts from a very high address and grows downwords as functions are called. 
    Function frames, local variables, return addresses etc. get memory from this segment. As Elias pointed out, 
    this stack is very different from stack data structure. This is a memory segment where is that is a style in 
    organizing data. The only common thing in them is that they grow dynamically in LIFO manner.

Coming to your question, you need to declare a pointer in global space like

```
my_struct *foo;
```

and in main(), you can allocate required memory dynamically and make this pointer to point to that memory

```
foo = calloc(10, sizeof (my_struct));
```

and when you need to deallocate the memory you can use realloc() to resize it.

malloc(), calloc() do not work on global data segment. malloc library hogs a big fat chunk of memory by extending the break point while initializing and hosts dynamic memory allocations done using malloc() et al in that memory area.

[image: A typical memory layout of a C program.]

Comment: This is all detail particular to *some* implementations, and also irrelevant to the question. I have programmed on embedded systems that had no heap, no text segment, no data segment, and no stack variables (not all at once!)